# Concourse time resource not triggered on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, concourse

I'm new to concourse and really excited to start working with it but I have a problem running the hello world example described here: https://concourse-ci.org/hello-world.html (example with time resource)

I'm running this example on Mac OS X (El Capitan) with a standalone binary of concourse. I slightly edited my pipeline for mac to look like this:

```
resources:
- name: every-1m
  type: time
  source: 
    interval: 1m

jobs:
- name: navi
  plan:
  - get: every-1m
    trigger: true
  - task: annoy
    config:
      platform: darwin
      run:
        path: echo
        args: ["Hey! Listen!"]
```

But for some reason the time resource is not triggered. The job 'navi' is never started. Any idea why this would happen?
Does it have anything to do with OS X?

When I directly trigger the navi job I get the following: [every 1m - no versions available (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMi4P.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running your worker on OS X. All the built-in resources require at least 1 worker in your pool that support the linux platform. This would account for the time resource never firing.

Comment: Does this mean I can't use built-in resources for a task running on OS X? Or can I flag the OS X worker as being able to handle those built-in resources?

Comment: You need a real linux worker to run on OS X. You can run the binaries in docker if you want to run on OS X. https://github.com/concourse/concourse-docker